# Eclipse add errors to "Problems" tab

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I add errors to the Problems tab?

I'm trying to create an external builder will run before building the Java project and do some processing to the source files, then I need to add the errors to the "Problems" tab.

Comment: Add errors to your code and then you will have new entries in that tab.

Comment: @Tom                this is where you really want an "Error"...haha

Comment: @ha9u63ar He want errors, so he get some :) :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an `IMarker` to the `IFile` resource. Something like:

```
IMarker marker = file.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);

marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line number of the error);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "your error message");
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
```

This code needs to be run in an Eclipse plugin.